# Select tag class and send it as a parameter through a function in ionic / angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Hope you can help me with this since I'm pretty new working with ionic and angular

I'm just trying to share data between pages using push method.

I have page1 and page2, in page1 let's suppose I have something like this

```
  <div class="whatever"(click)="goPage2($divclass)">
          <h1> lorem ipsum </h1>        
  </div>
```

I need to know how to get the div's class "whatever" to put it in a variable that I can use later to send it through goPage2() function

```
  goPage2($value){
        this.navCtrl.push(page2, {param: $value});
        console.log($value);
  }
```

And once I got into page2, how could i get this passed param to do whatever I want  with it, I'm trying something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the string `"whatever"` in a property on your component, then use it to set the class value on your element (with `ngClass`) and pass it through the event as an argument:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="divClass" (click)="goPage2(divClass)"></div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  divClass = "whatever";

  goPage2($value){
    this.navCtrl.push(page2, {param: $value});
    console.log($value);
  }
}
```

More information on the `ngClass` directive here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass.

Comment: nice! and something else I'm fighting with, is that I want to bind data in a css class, for example if I have <div class="color"> </div> I want to do something like <div class="{{element.color}"> </div> is that possible?

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes, you can do that. Here is a stackblitz demonstrating all the different ways you can set the class value dynamically: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-np1fxk.  Please consider upvoting the answer (up arrow) so others know it was helpful and accepting (check mark) so that others know your question has been answered. Welcome to SO :)